# Problems after separation part of a mesh

Tags: modeling

I am learning how to destroy a building with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dTcz5wWvVE)

[image]

The part of the building that gets smashed is separated from the main building (one large mesh).

[image]

Somehow some artefacts have been created.

[image]

What is wrong and how to repair this ? Or better go back and separate the "smashed part" again ?

Hmmm ... now I notice that there are some problems with that left column too .... ????

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a traditional normal issue, your faces are turned to the inside of the object.
It actually happens in both your objects, the 'shard' and the rest of the building.

Enter edit mode, select one of the darkened faces, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to select grouped and choose *Normal* to select faces facing in the same direction (check the selection for unwanted non-darkened faces and deselect any that don't apply)

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to make normals consistent across the surface.

Repeat for the red frames on the building too, they also seem to be facing inwards.

[image: Normals]

Comment: thanks I will try. What is causing the "normal issue" ? I did recalculate but that did not help

Comment: In computer 3D models faces always have a front facing side (and a backface). It is mostly irrelevant for rendering, but can cause issues while modeling, or with modifiers, Boolean operations and viewport display. Depends on how you modeled it or which technique you used to 'break it apart'. Faces often get incorrectly flipped with certain operations, modifiers, through incorrect modeling procedures or often simple user mistake. It's mostly harmless, and recalculating them often fixes the problem.